# Discord mute command received TypeError: fn is not a function

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I receive the following error:

```
C:\Users\(private)\discord\bots\(private)\node_modules\@discordjs\collection\dist\index.js:161
            if (fn(val, key, this))
                ^

TypeError: fn is not a function
```

Code related to the error:

```js
// This is in the discord.js module
 find(fn, thisArg) {
        if (typeof thisArg !== 'undefined')
            fn = fn.bind(thisArg);
        for (const [key, val] of this) {
            if (fn(val, key, this))
                return val;
        }
        return undefined;
    }
```

And my code if it helps. I've dumbed it down to a simple console.log for testing purposes:

```js
\\ not everything is here, just the important stuff.
const target = message.guild.members.cache.find(args[0])
console.log(target.roles.forEach(role => console.log(role.id)))
```

Comment: What is `args[0]`? Can you provide a [mcve]?

Comment: The error is definitely in your code, you're using the module wrong. You're supposed to pass a function to `find`, not some static value.

Comment: Brian McCutchon, `args[0]` is a string; a user id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's because [`.find()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=find) accepts a function as an argument but you provided a string. It returns the first item where the given function returns a truthy value. You could find a member by checking if their `id` property is the same as `args[0]`:

```js
message.guild.members.cache.find((member) => member.id == args[0])
```

But you should probably use the [`.get()`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/collection/master/class/Collection?scrollTo=get) method, which is faster, to get a member by their ID:

```js
const target = message.guild.members.cache.get(args[0])
```